# LightTable for Windows and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, windows-7-x64, node-webkit, lighttable

I'm trying to use LightTable on windows7 with a node-webkit application i'm building, when i add the nodejs connection and link to my file "main.js" (my app's starting point) i'm getting this:

The node process exited.

The node process you were connected to suddenly quit. Check the console for more information.

node[stderr]:
connect error:Error: connect ENOENT
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at Object.afterConnect as oncomplete

What i'm I doing wrong? how to fix it? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like since i'm trying to develop a node-webkit app, stuff like the window object are also available in the same context, and the nodejs connection wasn't able to handle it and shut down, this behavior doesn't seem right in any case but removing the "alert" lines solved the issue.

I would prefer if it doesn't close the connection but only throw the error and let me fix it and continue but i may be missing something here. I created an issue in the github project:

https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/1322

Also, i created this entry in the LightTable group to look for answers on how to setup the best environment to develop node-webkit applications in LightTable:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/_moWl1KQWf8

More info there...

Thanks.